# Problems of solid geometry

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

> 1) Determine the volume of a triangular prism not right in which the base has sides of $26 cm$, $28cm$ and  $30cm$. One lateral edge is $52 cm$ and it's projection on the plane of the base is 20 cm.
>
> 2)The base of a parallelepiped is a rectangle $ABCD$ in which $AB:BC=5:2$ and $AC=6\sqrt{29}$ cm. The height of the parallelepiped is $8cm$ and the projection of the summit $A'$ of the upper base, on the lower base, conincide with the meeting point $O$ of the diagonals. Determine the lateral area and volume.

In the first problem I have determined the area of the triangle with the formula of Erone, and it is 336 $cm^2$. So to determine the volume I did
$V=A_{b}\cdot h=336cm^2\cdot 20cm=6720 cm^3$ but the result is 16128$cm^3$. Where is the mistake?

In the second problem I have determined the sides of the base, $AB=30 cm$ and $BC=12 cm$, so the perimeter of the rectangle is 84cm. Since half of a diagonal of the rectangle is $A0=3\sqrt{29}cm$ and $A'O=8cm$, I have determined $AA'=5\sqrt{13}cm$, but how can I find the lateral area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The altitude of our prism is
$$\sqrt{52^2-20^2}=4\sqrt{13^2-5^2}=4\cdot12=48$$ and the area of the base it's indeed,$336.$

Thus, $V=336\cdot48=16128.$

The hint for the second problem.

Let $K$ and $M$ be midpoints of $AD$ and $AB$ respectively.

Thus, $A'M$ and $A'K$ are altitudes of parallelograms $ABB'A'$ and $ADD'A'$.

I am sure that you'll end the solution by yourself.

Comment: Of course man! I was really stupid, thanks.

Comment: @L.G.A.G I  added the hint for the second problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I found $A'M$ and $A'K$ with the Pythagoras's theorem and the rest are only calculations. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @L.G.A.G. You are welcome!

Comment: Sorry but i did not quite understand why $A'M$ and $A'K$ are altitudes, i.e. who ensures this?

Comment: @L.G.A.G. Because $AD\perp A'O$ and $AD\perp OK$. Thus, $AD$ perpendicular to all line in the plain $(KOA')$ and from here $AD\perp A'K$. Similarly we can prove that $A'M\perp AB$.

Comment: Ok then justifies it with the theorem of three perpendicular. Thanks

Comment: @L.G.A.G. Yes of course! But I don't like this theorem because if we need to solve a hard problem with perpendicular lines then it does not help.

Comment: Ok thanks so much!